# Check if object element exists in array

Tags: javascript, node.js

After some web scraping I have an array of names called `someObjArr`.

Array looks like this:
`[ { name: Joe 'Panik' } ]`

I want to check if a name exists in this array and here is my code:

For Example:

```
        var someObjArr = [];

        var filter = $('a.player-link').each(function(i, element) {
        var text = $(this).text();
        if(someObjArr[i] == undefined){
            someObjArr[i] = {};
        };
        someObjArr[i].name = text;

        function nameExistsInArray(name, array) {
            for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)(function(obj) {
                if(obj.name == name) {
                    return true;
                }
            })
            return false;
        };
            var exists = nameExistsInArray('Joe Panik', [{ name: 'Joe Panik' }]);
            console.log(exists);
        });
```

The output from this script return false fir every item in the array.

Comment: because you compare an Object with a String!

Comment: How would I compare an object in this situation?

Comment: that might help: [check-if-object-is-already-present-in-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453512/check-if-object-is-already-present-in-array)

Comment: Sweet i'll check it out. Thanks!

Comment: Changed my OP to reflect suggestions made from comments.

Comment: I dont  exactly get the poit what are you trying to do here if you have objects why you are trying to put them into an array and anyway without stringifying them you cannot do that way if you explain mod eclear what is the aim here exactly i will try to help

Comment: right now you don't ask if the `personExists` from anywere outside that function.

Comment: Looks like `var check = personExists([{Name: 'Joe Panik'}]);` is dead code, it is preceded by a `return` statement,  You will certainly benefit by formatting your code, and by using meaninful variable names

Comment: I am trying to use someObjArr to validate names from another scrape before inserting into SQL database

Comment: Thank you for all of the comments unfortunately I still don't understand! I am too new to javascript and coding in general.

Comment: "Oh, and you convert the array into a Boolean and then call length on it." Thanks. What do you mean?

Comment: I just want "check" to return 1 if it is present or 0 if not.

Comment: To repeat Wand Maker, you first need to move `var check = personExists([{name: 'Joe Panik'}]);` and `console.log(check);` out of the `personExists` function or nothing will happen.

Comment: @sails4life - You are not supposed to add your final working answer to your question.  That is not how StackOverflow works.  If the answer you went with was offered here already, then you just check the green checkmark to the left of that answer to indicate your question is now answered and to show which one you selected.  If you came up with your own answer, then you add your own answer (not in your question).

Comment: `for (...)(function () { ... })` what it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
function nameExistsInArray(name, array) { 
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i].Name == name) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
};
```

Usage:

```
var exists = nameExistsInArray('Joe Panik', [{ Name: 'Joe Panik' }]);
```

Explanation: You want to determine if some name of type `string` is equal to one of the `Name` properties of the `object`s in an `array`.

In our function, we'll pass a `string` name and an `array` of `object`s with `Name` properties. Then, we'll iterate through each `obj` in `array` using a `for` loop, and then we'll access the `Name` property and compare it with the `name` argument. When we see it, `return true`, but if we've iterated through every element and haven't found a match, we'll `return false`.

Comment: `Array.forEach` uses a closure. In your example, `nameExistsInArray` will always return `false`. Use a normal `for` loop.

Comment: I updated my OP with your code. I had to add a little because obj is undefined in yours. Unfrtunatly it still produces a false for each item in the array.

Comment: My one question would be is there a way to make it return a single true or false as opposed to one for each loop

Comment: The function actually *does* return a single `true` or `false` value. That's because it will only return if the `if` statement conditional is met, or if the loop is over.

Comment: It returns one true or false for your exmaple but in my array I have 300 people it it. It checks each one and returns a true or false.